# Linear Regression: How to find the correlation between estimators

Tags: regression

I was wondering if it would be possible to get the correlation between  $\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1$ in the linear regression model $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i+\varepsilon_i$.
If so, how should I derive such an expression?
(Let's assume $\varepsilon_i$ ~ independent with mean 0 and finite variance > 0.)
Since I am not very used to advanced statistics, a detailed explanation would be very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

The estimates $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}=( \hat{\beta_0}, \hat{\beta_1}$) are given by formula $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}=(X'X)^{-1}X'Y$. Variance of this vector of estimates is $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}=\sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}$, where $X$ is a matrix with two columns - first of ones, the second of $x_i$, and $\sigma^2$ is the variance of errors. The $(X'X)^{-1}$ matrix is given by:

$(X'X)^{-1} = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \sum x_i \\
 \sum x_i & \sum x_i^2 \end{array} \right)^{-1}= \frac{1}{det (X'X)} \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
 \sum x_i^2 & -\sum x_i \\
 -\sum x_i & n \end{array} \right)=\frac{1}{n\sum x_i^2 - (\sum x_i)^2 }\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
 \sum x_i^2 & -\sum x_i \\
 -\sum x_i & n \end{array} \right)$

Correlarion between the two estimates should then be $\frac{-\sum x_i}{\sqrt{n\sum x_i^2}}$.

Comment: You mean that the variance of the vector β hat is (x'x)^-1, right? And how did you derive the (X′X)^−1 matrix?

Comment: The variance of the vector is the matrix you wrote times the variance of errors. I will edit the answer, so that it shows in LaTeX.